# How can I get to know whether the icon is the same?

Tags: c#

These days I am making a file explorer.

I get the icon of the file&directory like this.

```
 public static ImageSource FindIconForDirectory(string DirectoryName)
        {            
            SHFILEINFO shinfo = new SHFILEINFO();
            SHGetFileInfo(
                DirectoryName,
                0, ref shinfo, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shinfo),
                SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_LARGEICON);            
                using (Icon i = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(shinfo.hIcon))
                {
                    ImageSource img = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
                                            i.Handle,
                                            new Int32Rect(0, 0, i.Width, i.Height),
                                            BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

                }
            return img;
        }

 public static ImageSource FindIconForFilename(string fileName)
        {
            var icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(fileName);
            return  Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
                icon .Handle,
                Int32Rect.Empty,
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }
```

I got these two different ways above from the StackOverflow. The SHFILEINFO way strangely sometimes reports `System.ArgumentException: 'Arg_ArgumentException Arg_ParamName_Name'` error while getting the icon of the file that I have to use another way to achieve it.

Now I meet a problem. In the beginning, I store each ImageSource of the file in a List. However, as we know there are some directory contains many file&directory(such as C:\windows\system32). It takes a long time to get and store the ImageSource. (PS: I made a test in C:\windows\system32. It took about 3 seconds load all file info(without its icon) while took about 30 seconds load all file info(with its icon))

There are so many files and directories have the same icon. So it is unnecessary to store a brand new ImageSource pre-file/directory.

I can not achieve this by file extension. As you know, almost each .exe has a different icon.

How can I get to know whether the icon is the same? Thank you.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you need to be sure to call [`DestroyIcon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-destroyicon) on the handle in `shinfo.hIcon` after you have created an icon from it, otherwise you will have a resource leak.

Comment: I have to ask why would you want to “save” the icons? It sounds like you want to “compare” two images to see if they are the same image. Comparing images is doable (quick) like comparing the file sizes OR (not quick) opening each image and compare each pixel. Either way, if performance is an issue, comparing images is only going to reduce performance.

Comment: Emma...you are right. Would you please give me a suggestion? Thank you.@JohnG

Comment: I am not saving the icon in the disk, but save it in a list and render by wrappanel of WPF.@JohnG

Comment: I am still not understanding why you want to save the icon even in a list, you have the icon in the file why not use it instead of saving it? Also, from the comment in your question… _”There are so many files and directories have the same icon. So it is unnecessary to store a brand new ImageSource pre-file/directory.”_ … it will “almost always” take longer to compare two images that are the same than saving the same image file twice. Is HD space an issue? I am obviously missing something.

Comment: What @JohnG is saying is that in order to compare the icons, you still have to load them. You have stated that loading the images causes your program to slow down. Since you have to load them to compare them, comparing them will only be adding more steps, causing your program to be even slower. Now, if you are wanting to reduce the amount of memory used by the images, what you are requesting makes sense -- you could compare the images in some way and store them in some kind of cache in memory and reference them there so that you don't have duplicates in memory.

Comment: @Herohtar Yes, as you said, now I want to find some ways to compare the images to solve the duplicates. By the way, is there any good idea to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: I do not want to dissuade you from comparing the images, however, as we already know… comparing images pixel by pixel is NOT going to be fast. Obviously, this will depend on how many pixels are in each image. I have an image comparer and it simply checks each pixel. The images I compare are not Icons and have lots of pixels. Comparing a collection of say 4000+ files took approximately 2 days. Would it not be easier to get an image array of the common icons and use the file extension to determine the icon?

Comment: Also, since you stated that there are many duplicates, then performance is going to take a hit because it will have to loop through ALL the pixels in each image to know if they are the same. Usually, if the images are different, then we can get out of the check as soon as we get to a different pixel which will usually be found right away. In other words, for each image that is the same, the code will have to check “ALL” pixels in “each” image to determine if it is a duplicate.

Comment: @JohnG No, I don't want to compare each pixel. I wanna whether there is something unique just like MD5 or GUID can easily solve this.

Comment: @JohnG Or if there is any other better way to solve this performance problem. Please tell me about that. Thank you.

Comment: Well… it is difficult to say. Without knowing why, you are doing this, will only lead to speculation on my part. Therefore, I have one question… Your question starts…  _”These days I am making a file explorer.”_ … Why? Why reinvent the wheel unless this is a school project. What is the big picture where this “file explorer” and the posted code comes into play? From what I can see the posted code is simply retuning the icon from a given “directory” and “file.”

Comment: If the main question is “why is this so slow”… then I highly recommend you edit your post with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can test your code. If there something in the code causing the slow down, I am confident someone will see this OR suggest a different approach. Without the “COMPLETE” code that others can copy and paste to test, speculation is guaranteed.

Comment: Also, what platform are you targeting… Winforms?, WPF?, ASP? I was using winforms, however the posted code appears to be something else.

Comment: Using something like a hash (MD5) would likely be even *more* of a performance hit, because that requires performing some computation on the entire image beyond just directly comparing it. If your question now is "how do I compare images in C#?" I would suggest doing a Google search for that; there are already quite a few solutions on this site.

Comment: @JohnG I am using WPF, not so much differ from Winform.

Comment: @Herohtar It seems I can't improve the performance by avoiding loading duplicate imagesource. Now I am about to try another idea just like lazyloading in front-end.